# how to make a dropdown menu expanded whenever its nested menu is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

Here is my dropdown list [dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGhQE.png)
but when I click on one of the nested menu in the dropdown(for example:Books Registration), on that page the dropdown menu is collapsed when that page loads, like this [Collapsed Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM7EH.png), and here is the dropdown code

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level">
<li id="BooksRegistration">
<a href="BooksRegistration.php"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Books Registration </a>
</li>
<li id="AuthorRegistration">
<a href="AuthorRegistration.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Author Registration </a>
</li>
<li id="MembersRegistration">
<a href="MembersRegistration.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Members Registration </a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">Second Level Link<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
<ul class="nav nav-third-level">
<li>
```

So I need you guys to show me how can I make the dropdown list expanded when on of the nested page in that dropdown list is loaded.
I need the Javascript code because I cannot work with jQuery

Comment: MAO, can you provide css as well. Better way create [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: .top-navbar .dropdown-menu{
    min-width: 230px;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    }.top-navbar .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .top-navbar .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus{
color: #225081;
background:none;
}
.dropdown-tasks{
width: 255px;
}
.dropdown-tasks .progress {
height: 8px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border-radius: 0px;
}
.dropdown-tasks > li > a { 
padding: 0px 15px;
}
.dropdown-tasks p {
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 21px;
padding-top: 4px;
}
.active-menu {
background-color: rgba(255, 10, 10, 0.44);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use any browser which provides inspect element feature active that on your dropdown list (In chrome Right click On the dropdown list and then click on the inspect) then toggle your dropdown list at same time look at the css in the inspected side that which class are being changed copy those classes ( that add them to each page which are in dropdown list)
see my example
[image]

Those highlighted class or attributes in the style are being shown when click the dropdown list so then I copied those attribute when the dropdown list is being expanded and added them to each page in the dropdown list